# How can I remove a swf file that's embedded in html using a button in the swf?

Tags: html, flash, embed

I have a swf file that's embedded in a html page, and I have a close button in the swf page, I want the swf to disappear when I click on the button, what is the best way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ursing swfobject 2.1 to embed the swf you can use this built-in javascript swfobject.removeSWF() function:

```
function removeFlashFromHTML() 
{
 swfobject.removeSWF("id_of_your_html_object");
}
```

now you call the javascript function from flash using ExternalInterface:

```
function buttonClicked(evt:MouseEvent) 
{
 if (ExternalInterface.available) {
  ExternalInterface.call("removeFlashFromHTML()");
 }
}
```

for more information about SWFObject check [this](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) website

Answer (score 1):

Write a JavaScript function that will hide the swf or its containing element, and call that function via the "close button" in the swf itself.

Answer (score 1):

[Heres](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=0922A) an article on how to get flash to call some JS on your page. If you never want it back (after hiding) i suggest you [remove it from the DOM](http://www.dustindiaz.com/add-and-remove-html-elements-dynamically-with-javascript/) to release resources, as flash is expensive in client environments.

Comment: Removing an html snippet that holds the swf stops the flash player plug-in?